# No sound after suspend only on new kernels

Tags: sound, kernel, suspend, pulseaudio, alsa

*Simple*, no sound after suspension. Pavucontrol show that everything is exactly the same, so do the logs.
This bug only occurs on kernel version 5.2 or above.
On the side note, HDMI audio doesn't work on any kernels I have tested.

Temporary Fixes:

- Reboot
- [This little script that re-scans the PCI.](https://pastebin.com/VrpfDNiv) Also works for HDMI audio, just kinda finds it.

> Why wouldn't you use old kernels then?

Touchpad has *blind spot* on them.

> Why wouldn't you use this script

It works randomly, sometimes breaking the sound completely, where only reboot fixes it.

Tried, didn't work:

- Restarting Pulseaudio and Alsa, even reinstalling Pulse
- `snd_hda_intel.probe_mask=0x01`
- Using **EVERY** Linux distro I could download and try, Fedora, Arch, Manjaro, Linux Mint, Ubuntu even MX Linux.

Machine: Acer E1-731
Soundcard: ALC269VB

Logs: [lspci](https://pastebin.com/5jVVULzm), [dmesg | grep audio](https://pastebin.com/zc4fLGvU).

EDIT: Kernel Versions down and including 5.1.9 don't have this problem, it only occurs on version 5.2 up and including (checked on Arch Linux).

[Link to the changelog for 5.2](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v5.x/ChangeLog-5.2), as there should be the culprit.

I tried to check few of those changes myself, rebuilding the kernel with different versions of patch_realtek.c.
But to no avail.

Already check the version from after `607ca3bd220f4022e6f5356026b19dafc363863a` commit.

EDIT 2:
Linux image 5.1.9, built with latest elantech.c and elantech.h module source files builds just fine, sound and touchpad work perfectly. On Arch the HDMI audio works fine too.

I have reported this bug already, because it doesn't change the logs (and occurs only on one machine) it's a pain to remove. So for now I will just wait for someone to fully repair it.

Comment: Great question - have you lodged a bug issue against the kernel on Github?

Comment: I did lodged a bug issue on Bugzilla, some 3 months ago. I don't really know how to report it on GitHub so never really tried it.